# URL quoted forward slash in self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, target_status_code=200)

Tags: django, url, testcase, quote

I have the following TestCase

```
def testNoAccessWithoutLogin(self):
    """
    Tests that redirected to the login page if you are not logged in
    """
    response = self.client.get(reverse('expenseList'), follow=True)
    expected_url = reverse('login') + "?next=" + reverse('expenseList')
    self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, 
        target_status_code=200)
    expected_url = reverse('login') + "?next=" + reverse('purchaseList')
    response = self.client.get(reverse('purchaseList'), follow=True)
    self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, 
        target_status_code=200)
# end testNoAccessWithoutLogin
```

And I am getting a fail with

> ==================================================================== FAIL: testNoAccessWithoutLogin (procurement.tests.expenseTests)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/jason/public_html/activity/project/procurement/tests.py", line
>   66, in testNoAccessWithoutLogin
>       target_status_code=200)   File "/Users/jason/.virtualenvs/activity/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py",
>   line 304, in assertRedirects
>       (url, expected_url)) AssertionError: Response redirected to 'http://testserver/login/?next=%2Fprocurement%2FexpenseList%2F',
>   expected 'http://testserver/login/?next=/procurement/expenseList/'

I assume this is because "%2F" is not equal to "/", but why is the url in response being quoted?

The function being tested is decorated with

```
@login_required
```

Comment: You haven't said how `expenseList` is doing the redirect. Are you using the `login_required` decorator? It needs to urlencode the querystring parameters in case they contain characters like `#` or `&`, however, the forward slash [should not be quoted](https://github.com/django/django/blob/d72f8862cb1a39934952e708c3c869be1399846e/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L134).

Comment: Yes, expenseList is decorated with @login_required. I tried using urllib.quote and unquote on expected_url to get it to match, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `next` query parameter value is URL encoded; so you would have to do the same to validate the redirect.

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('expenseList'), follow=True)
expected_url = reverse('login') + "?next=" + urllib.quote(reverse('expenseList'), "")
self.assertRedirects(response, expected_url, status_code=302, 
    target_status_code=200)
```

Note the second argument to `urllib.quote` is `""`, as

```
urllib.quote(string[, safe])
```

> Replace special characters in string using the %xx escape. Letters, digits, and the characters '_.-' are never quoted. By default, this function is intended for quoting the path section of the URL.The optional safe parameter specifies additional characters that should not be quoted — **its default value is '/'**.

Source [docs on python.org](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote).

Comment: Thanks. I should of thought of that. I tried quoting, unquoting etc but on the whole URL, not just the query  parameter.